# Using pagination with foreach roop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

Below code include roop statement and pagination.
I'm also wish to follow MVC style coding, but in this case I have to use @if statement in below view.

There was an error when I tried to filter by @if(!deleted_at == null), but I couldn't show correct pagination, because also this code counting with "(deleted_at == null)", so result was incorrect pagination numbers shown.

How could I modify this code to get the correct pagination result when after passing this controller?

I think the error came from using Where() with Orwhere().
Thanks:)

**Search box by user_name and customer_name**

[image]

**index.php**

```
 <div style="overflow-x: auto; display: inline-flex;">
   {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form', 'method' => 'get', 'url' => url('/stopjobs/job_finished_search_date'))) !!} 
   {{ Form::input('text', 'datepicker_from', null, ['placeholder' => 'Fra', 'id' => 'datepicker_from']) }}
    &nbsp;
   {{ Form::input('text', 'datepicker_to', null, ['placeholder' => 'Til', 'id' => 'datepicker_to']) }} 
        {!! Form::submit('Søke', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
    &nbsp;
   {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form', 'method' => 'get', 'url' => url('/stopjobs/job_finished_search_name'))) !!}
   {!! Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Bruker eller Kunde']) !!}
   {!! Form::submit('Søke', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) !!} 
   {!! Form::close() !!}
 </div>
```

**controller**

```
public function job_finished_search_name(Request $request) 
{ 
    $jobs = Job::onlyTrashed()
    ->where('user_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%')
    ->orwhere('customer_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%')
    ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15);

    return view('stopjobs.index', ['jobs' => $jobs]); 
}
```

**view**

```
<tbody>
@foreach($jobs as $job)
    @if(!$job->deleted_at == null)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $job->id !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $job->user_name !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $job->created_at !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $job->deleted_at !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $job->usedTime() !!}</td>
    </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
{{ $jobs->links()}}
```

Comment: soft deleted models will automatically be excluded from query results. why have you put this check???

read this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: @ParthShah, I already using softdeleted in Model, so I have deleted_at date in the server. If you want to check deleted date in the view, then how could you do it instead of using in the other places like model and controller?

Comment: so you only want to display trashed data???

Comment: @ParthShah, I wish to get the correct pagination number in this case :), get the trashed data is not problem.:)

Comment: What about `@if($job->deleted_at != null)`?

Comment: @Tpojka, I modified question, could you give some help?;)

Comment: With this `$jobs = Job::onlyTrashed()` you can remove the if statment `@if(!$job->deleted_at == null)` it will not find a job with `deleted_at == null` !!

Comment: Just pointed that your condition could give you falsy result. If in any case `Job` would be `true`, `!Job` would't be `null` but rather `false`. In your condition you are checking if `not-something-that-you-don't-know-what-it-is is equal to null`, in my example you would check if `any-given-value is specifically not equal to null`. It is semantic but sometimes would be hard to debug in a way you wrote. Probably not problem solver but rather better practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you query your jobs, do it with `where` statement. There's no other way

```
$jobs = Job::whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
```

Comment: I already use "Job::onlyTrashed()" in this controller. thanks.

Comment: Then you need to check documentation again https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models onlyTrashed means **all** the returning records will be deleted, so `deleted_all` never will be null. Maybe you wanted to use `withTrashed`, which will return you all the records, deleted or not. But in your view you **only** want to see **not-deleted** records, so there's no need to use `withTrashed` here.

Comment: And I undertood that backwards since I dind't noticed the `!` symbol 

Comment: I modified question, could you give some help?;)

Comment: You don't need that `if` in your view, you're already filtering to get only that jobs that `deleted_at !== null` with `onlyTrashed`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only soft deleted data with pagination then try this

```
$jobs = Job::onlyTrashed()
                ->where('key', 'value')
                ->paginate();
```

Comment: I'm using this. $jobs = Job::onlyTrashed()
        ->where('user_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%')
        ->orwhere('customer_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%')
        ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15);
where is incorrect to get the correct result with view include a foreach and pagination? thanks.

Comment: I think problem is where and orWhere condition which also fetch not deleted data. If this is the case you have to use this where(function ($q) use ($data) { $q->where();$q->orWhere(); });

Comment: I did it, but it's not to be solution to get the correct pagination.;(